# Evitar copias de una app

Tags: java, android

ya había hecho una pregunta similar, me dijeron que use licencias de Google para poder evitar que los usuarios puedan compartir mi aplicación mediante Bluetooth u otro medio. Pero no me sirvió, al final opté por obtener el ID de android y compararlo con SharedPreferences, la idea sería que al pasar la aplicación por Bluetooth se compruebe que no es el mismo dato por lo que se mostraría como copia ilegal, así es como lo hice:

```
String ID = Secure.getString(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    myPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(SplashActivity.this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor myEditor = myPreferences.edit();



        //Aqui comprobamos si es copia
        String name = myPreferences.getString("NOMBRE", "unknown");
        if (name.equals("")) {
            myEditor.putString("NOMBRE", ID);
            myEditor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No es copia", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (!name.equals(ID)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Es copia", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Probablemente tenga una idea erronea de cómo hacerlo, pero al final lo que quiero es evitar que un usuario de paga pueda compartir la app. De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Puedes encontrar información aquí.  https://source.android.com/devices/drm

Comment: Te dejo otro link con informacion. [https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html]

Comment: @Roby No creo que puedas evitar la copia de una aplicación. Te recomiendo utilizar un servicio, por ejemplo, de suscripción.

Comment: Me he topado con un par de apps que si las pasabas por bluetooth la aplicación se cerraba sin previo aviso, pero si las descargabas por la play store funcionaba bien. Es lo que quiero lograr pero que en vez de que se cierre sin aviso, se vaya a una pantalla donde le impediría continuar el programa.

Answer (score 0):

Evitar que se copie la app es casi imposible, cualquier usuario medianamente interesado puede decompilar y acceder a cualquier archivo instalada en el cliente.
Los dispositivos son ambientes no seguros,puedes implementar técnicas para disuadir copias como:

- ofuscar el código (hay alternativas profesionales a proguard)
- Implementar seguridad con un servidor
- Encriptar la base de datos

Todas estas cosas hacen más difícil el crear una copia de la app, pero a la larga un atacante determinado puede evitar todos estos obstáculos.